# How to add a feature on a ArcGIS Feature Service with a Geocortex Workflow

Tags: feature-service, geocortex, workflow

Do you know the correct Geocortex workflow to add a feature to a layer of a ArcGIS Feature Service?

I'm using the Geocortex Workflow Designer 4.9.2.46. I know it's easier to add a feature with the Geocortex Workflow Designer 5.

The sequence of activities I'm currently using is the following:

1. Display Capture Geometry
2. Display Form
3. Add To Dictionary (here I'm adding the Captured Geometry to the dictionary returned by the form)
4. Convert the dictionary to a DataTable
5. Convert the DataTable to a FeatureSet
6. AddFeatures

The feature is effectively created but the geometry attribute is missing. I don't know how to update this geometry field. In the database, this geometry field is called *shape*.

Answer (score 2):

A FeatureSet is a collections of Graphic objects - Graphic objects have a Geometry associated with them.

When you convert your DataTable to a FeatureSet, that operation will not consider a shape field and your geometry will get lost.

Rather than adding the captured geometry to the dictionary, you should set the captured geometry on the Graphic object that is found within the FeatureSet you created.

You may also want to set the Fields of your FeatureSet before sending it to the server, depending on what other operations happen in the meantime.  When a client activity is run in Geocortex Workflow, all of the in-state objects will be serialized for transfer to the client.  If you do not set the fields of a FeatureSet then all of its fields may be converted to String type when this happens.  This is only a consideration if you're using client activities (like Alert!) between the creation of your FeatureSet and the Add Features activity.

Answer (score 0):

it's not that hard, once you've done it once.  I struggled the 1st time.   I have some samples I can help.
  poliart . com